# Automate an "Approve/Deny" Email with a button (PHP,MYSQL)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, automated-tests

I find myself stuck in creating the last functionality of my project. I need to make a button that 'approves' or 'denies' a request and sends an email to the person with their answer(approve or denied). I'm doing this mainly PHP and MySQL. Based on what I've read I keep seeing that JavaScript is needed for a task as such. Also, I figure I need to have another table in sql with the list of names and emails of the people who are going to be receiving the emails (but im not sure). Please I need some guidance on how to procced on making my last functionality.

requestlog.php

```
 <?php
    $conn = new mysqli('','','', '');
    
    //if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    //}
    //else{
      //    echo "success";
    //}
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/hndrx.css" />
    
    </head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
    
    
    th:nth-child(even),td:nth-child(even) {
    
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Request Log</h1>
      <p>Admin can make any changes as needed</p>
      <div style="padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #f5f5f5; display: inline-block;">
                    
                    <b>DISPLAY:</b> 
                    <a display="yes" name="yes" class="hndrx" href="adminnrequestlog.php?display_y_n=yes">YES</a>
                    <a display="no" name="no" class="hndrx" href="adminnrequestlog.php?display_y_n=no">NO</a>
                    <a display="all" name="all" class="hndrx" href="adminnrequestlog.php">ALL</a>
        
                </div>
                
                
    
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Advisor Name</th>
                                    <th>Customer #</th>
                                    <th>Coin Description</th>
                                    <th>Max Budget</th>
                                    <th>Minimum Grade</th>
                                    <th>Desired ETA</th>
                                    <th>Additional Notes</th>
                                    <th>Buyer Notes</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Sold</th>
                                    <th>Display</th>
                                    <th>Date Submitted</th>
                                    <th>Update</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                            </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php include 'admin-read.php';?>
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
     <!-- <form class="form-inline m-2" action="admincreate.php" method="POST">
        <label for="advisor">Advisor 3 Digit MOM Credential:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="advisor" name="advisor">    
        <label for="customer">Customer #</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="customer" name="customer">
        <label for="description">Coin Description:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="description" name="description">
        <label for="budget">Max Budget:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="budget" name="budget">
        <label for="grade">Minimum Grade:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="grade" name="grade">
        <label for="deadline">Desired ETA:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="deadline" name="deadline">
        <label for=" notes">Additional Notes:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="notes" name="notes">
        <!--<label for="admin_notes">Admin Notes:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="admin_notes" name="admin_notes">
        <label for="status">Status:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" id="status" name="status"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </form> -->
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>


    <?php
```

read.php

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    
      include 'db.php';
    
        $where = array();
        if( isset($_GET['display_y_n']) ){
            $where[] = '
            display_y_n = "'.$_GET['display_y_n'].'"
            ';
        }
    
        $where_string = '';
        if( count($where) > 0 ){
            $where_string = '
            where
                '.implode('&&', $where).'
            ';
        }
    
        $sql = "
        select * from requestlog
        ".$where_string;
    
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
    
        $row_echo = "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['advisor'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['customer'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['budget'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['grade'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['deadline'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['admin_notes'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['sold'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['display_y_n'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= "<td>" . $row['timestamp'] . "</td>";
        $row_echo.= '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="adminrequestlog.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" role="button">Update</a></td>';
    
    
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            if ($row['id'] == $_GET['id']) {
                $row_echo = '<form class="form-inline mr-2" action="adminupdate.php" method="POST">';
                //$row_echo.= '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="advisor" value="'.$row['advisor'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer" value="'.$row['customer'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="'.$row['description'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="budget" value="'.$row['budget'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="grade" value="'.$row['grade'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="deadline" value="'.$row['deadline'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="notes" value="'.$row['notes'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin_notes" value="'.$row['admin_notes'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="status" value="'.$row['status'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sold" value="'.$row['sold'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="display_y_n" value="'.$row['display_y_n'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="timestamp" value="'.$row['timestamp'].'"></td>';
                $row_echo.= '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></td>';
                // $row_echo.= '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
                $row_echo.= '</form>';
            }
        }
    
        echo $row_echo;
    
        echo '<td><a class="btn btn-danger"  href="admindelete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" Onclick="return ConfirmDelete();" role="button">Delete</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    
    ?>
    
    <script>
        function ConfirmDelete()
        {
          return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        }
    </script> 
    
    
    <?php $conn->close(); ?>
```

Comment: What's your question about this? Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem? Also, be warned that your database query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection

Comment: Thats the thing, I'm not sure where im making my probelm. I tried a couple of ways in trying to automate the email but its not included in this code since it kept breaking. I need to know which method will be best in automating the 'approve/deny' email

Comment: There is no 'best'. You can do this with JavaScript and Ajax and PHP, or you can submit your form and do it with just PHP. Your choice is likely governed by how it fits with the rest of the system. Beyond that there's too little focus here to give a succinct answer

Comment: Okay, I’ll give this another try. I think I’m going to try it only using PHP since I’m not familiar with Ajax and js